# Creating NSArray - EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, out-of-memory

When I try to create the `NSArray purchasedTimeArray`, I get a crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
NSString *blank = @"";
NSArray *purchasedTimeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                   timeRemainingTitle, blank, @"imagename.png", blank, description, 4, nil];
```

And yes, `timeRemainingTitle` and `description` still exist in memory. They are both NSStrings.

Comment: '4' isn't an object, it's an int.  You would need to use an 'NSNumber' to wrap '4' within.

Comment: In new objective-c syntax it would be @4

Comment: Man. Totally overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the new Objective-C syntax:

```
NSArray *purchasedTimeArray = @[ timeRemainingTitle, blank, @"imagename.png", blank, description, @4 ];
```

Two benefits:

1. Much easier to write.
2. No need for `nil` terminator and if one of the other values are `nil` in value, all the objects still end up in the array.

As noted in the comments, the `@4` syntax translates to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]`.

Comment: Wow. Shame on me for not knowing about the new syntax. Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend watching WWDC 2012 session 405. This covers all of the new features of modern Objective-C - lots of great stuff.